# mysql group by not doing what i am expecting?

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
SELECT
      bp.product_id,bs.step_number,
      p.price, pd.name as product_name
    FROM 
      builder_product bp
      JOIN builder_step bs ON bp.builder_step_id = bs.builder_step_id
      JOIN builder b ON bp.builder_id = b.builder_id
      JOIN product p ON p.product_id = bp.product_id
      JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
      WHERE b.builder_id = '74' and bs.optional != '1'
    group by bs.step_number
    ORDER by bs.step_number, p.price
```

but here is my results

```
88  1   575.0000    Lenovo Thinkcentre POS PC
244 2   559.0000    Touchscreen with MSR - Firebox 15&quot;
104 3   285.0000    Remote Order Printer - Epson
97  4   395.0000    Aldelo Lite
121 5   549.0000    Cash Register Express  - Pro
191 6   349.0000    Integrated Payment Processing
155 7   369.0000    Accessory - Posiflex 12.1&quot; LCD Customer Display
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how GROUP BY is supposed to work. If you group by a number of columns, your select can only return:

- The columns you group by
- Aggregation functions from other columns, such as MIN(), MAX(), AVG()...

So you'd need to do this:

```
SELECT
  bs.step_number,
  MIN(p.price) AS min_price, pd.name as product_name
FROM 
  builder_product bp
  JOIN builder_step bs ON bp.builder_step_id = bs.builder_step_id
  JOIN builder b ON bp.builder_id = b.builder_id
  JOIN product p ON p.product_id = bp.product_id
  JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
  WHERE b.builder_id = '74' and bs.optional != '1'
group by bs.step_number, pd.name
ORDER by bs.step_number, min_price
```

(MySQL allows a very relaxed syntax and will happily remove random rows for each group but other DBMS will trigger an error with your original query.)

Comment: i need the product_id for each of the min prices as well

Comment: For that, google for `strawberry query`. But please make sure you understand how plain `GROUP BY` works.

Answer (score 1):

Join to a sub select of the tables which only contain the min value of each group

In this example.  the mygroup min(amt) returns the lowest dollar item for a group

I then join this back to the main table as a full inner join to limit the records only to that minimum.

```
Select A.myGROUP, A.Amt
from mtest A
  INNER JOIN (Select myGroup, min(Amt) as minAmt from mtest group by mygroup) B
  ON B.myGroup=A.mygroup
  and B.MinAmt = A.Amt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Each different group key is returned only once. This problem is not easily solved. Run two distinct queries and combine results afterwards. IF this is not an option create a temporary table for the minimum price for each step join the tables in the query.